# Java 8 Stream.findAny() vs finding a random element in the stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

In my Spring application, I have a Couchbase repository for a document type of `QuoteOfTheDay`.  The document is very basic, just has an id field of type UUID, value field of type String and created date field of type Date.

In my service class, I have a method that returns a random quote of the day.  Initially I tried simply doing the following, which returned an argument of type `Optional<QuoteOfTheDay>`, but it would seem that findAny() would pretty much always return the same element in the stream.  There's only about 10 elements at the moment.

```
public Optional<QuoteOfTheDay> random() {
    return StreamSupport.stream(repository.findAll().spliterator(), false).findAny();
}
```

Since I wanted something more random, I implemented the following which just returns a `QuoteOfTheDay`.

```
public QuoteOfTheDay random() {
    int count = Long.valueOf(repository.count()).intValue();

    if(count > 0) {
        Random r = new Random();

        List<QuoteOfTheDay> quotes = StreamSupport.stream(repository.findAll().spliterator(), false)
                .collect(toList());

        return quotes.get(r.nextInt(count));
    } else {
        throw new IllegalStateException("No quotes found.");
    }
}
```

I'm just curious how the `findAny()` method of Stream actually works since it doesn't seem to be random.

Thanks.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The reason behind `findAny()` is to give a more flexible alternative to `findFirst()`. If you are not interested in getting a specific element, this gives the implementing stream more flexibility in case it is a parallel stream.

No effort will be made to randomize the element returned, it just doesn't give the same guarantees as `findFirst()`, and might therefore be faster.

This is what the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findAny--) says on the subject:

> *The behavior of this operation is explicitly nondeterministic; it is free to select any element in the stream. This is to allow for maximal performance in parallel operations; the cost is that multiple invocations on the same source may not return the same result. (If a stable result is desired, use findFirst() instead.)*

Answer (score 11):

Don’t collect into a `List` when all you want is a single item. Just pick one item from the stream. By picking the item via `Stream` operations you can even handle counts bigger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and don’t need the “interesting” way of hiding the fact that you are casting a long to an `int` (that `Long.valueOf(repository.count()).intValue()` thing).

```
public Optional<QuoteOfTheDay> random() {
    long count = repository.count();
    if(count==0) return Optional.empty();
    Random r = new Random();
    long randomIndex=count<=Integer.MAX_VALUE? r.nextInt((int)count):
        r.longs(1, 0, count).findFirst().orElseThrow(AssertionError::new);
    return StreamSupport.stream(repository.findAll().spliterator(), false)
        .skip(randomIndex).findFirst();
}
```